# Head Mounted Display I can connect to Mac or PC For Computer Use?

Tags: mac, display

I'd like to slip on a head mounted display instead of my monitor so I could lay on my bed or couch and surf the web or code. (I touch type so I don't need to see my keyboard as long as it's next to me I'm fine.)

I'm thinking maybe Microsoft Hololens would be able to do this and/or Oculur VR. But they don't really market themselves as devices to surf the web or code, or read text. I'm not into gaming, I just want a freaking monitor on my head if that makes sense.

I've been searching online forever but cannot find a solution. Maybe someone knows?

Answer (score 1):

With the Oculus Rift dev kit and [Virtual Desktop](http://www.vrdesktop.net) you can do anything you normally do on your computer, but in VR. You may have to experiment with positioning to get desired results if you are going to be laying down since normal view will be with your head straight and level.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that the question is for Mac. Maybe this can help you in your search anyway.